# Google charts : Line chart failing to animate on start up

Tags: google-visualization

I can't get my multi-line chart to animate on start up -
While I'm fetching data points for my multi line graph from the DB, I've added a sample of what the points would be in my code below:

```
<html>
  <head>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

        google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['line']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() 
        {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Count of Users');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Count of Items');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Count of Locations');

          data.addRows([
    [[8,07,06],1,181,181],
    [[8,08,52],1,73,73],
    [[8,09,43],1,204,204],
    [[8,10,06],1,209,209],
    [[8,10,27],1,334,334],
    [[8,10,47],1,345,345],
    [[8,12,24],1,852,852],
    [[8,13,52],1,317,317],
    [[8,43,01],1,538,538],
    [[8,51,53],1,50,50],
    [[8,55,01],1,50,50],
    [[8,55,30],1,99,99],
    [[8,56,27],1,51,51],
    [[8,57,11],1,50,50],
    [[8,57,58],1,50,50],
    [[8,58,32],1,50,50],
    [[8,59,42],1,16,16],
    [[9,08,54],1,16,16],
    [[9,09,41],1,2,2],
    [[9,10,07],1,9,9],
    [[9,10,53],1,35,35],
    [[9,11,31],1,4,4],
    [[9,11,45],1,3,3]
          ]);

          var options = {
                        title: 'Updated every 3 Hours',

                        chart: {
                                animation: {
                                            duration: 2000,
                                            easing: 'linear',
                                            startup: true
                                            },
                                },

                        width: 1000,
                        height: 500
                        };

          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
          chart.draw(data, options);
          }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

As of now a static multi line graph is rendered:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSLXq.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code(your console should have logged them)

1. `08` and `09` are not valid Number-values(should be `8` and `9`)
2. you load the wrong package(you must load `corechart`)
3. `animation` is not a property of `chart`

fixed chart:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Count of Users');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Count of Items');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Count of Locations');

  data.addRows([
    [
      [8, 7, 06], 1, 181, 181
    ],
    [
      [8, 8, 52], 1, 73, 73
    ],
    [
      [8, 9, 43], 1, 204, 204
    ],
    [
      [8, 10, 06], 1, 209, 209
    ],
    [
      [8, 10, 27], 1, 334, 334
    ],
    [
      [8, 10, 47], 1, 345, 345
    ],
    [
      [8, 12, 24], 1, 852, 852
    ],
    [
      [8, 13, 52], 1, 317, 317
    ],
    [
      [8, 43, 01], 1, 538, 538
    ],
    [
      [8, 51, 53], 1, 50, 50
    ],
    [
      [8, 55, 01], 1, 50, 50
    ],
    [
      [8, 55, 30], 1, 99, 99
    ],
    [
      [8, 56, 27], 1, 51, 51
    ],
    [
      [8, 57, 11], 1, 50, 50
    ],
    [
      [8, 57, 58], 1, 50, 50
    ],
    [
      [8, 58, 32], 1, 50, 50
    ],
    [
      [8, 59, 42], 1, 16, 16
    ],
    [
      [9, 8, 54], 1, 16, 16
    ],
    [
      [9, 9, 41], 1, 2, 2
    ],
    [
      [9, 10, 07], 1, 9, 9
    ],
    [
      [9, 10, 53], 1, 35, 35
    ],
    [
      [9, 11, 31], 1, 4, 4
    ],
    [
      [9, 11, 45], 1, 3, 3
    ]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Updated every 3 Hours',


    animation: {
      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'linear',
      startup: true
    },


    //width: 1000,
    //height: 500
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'm new to this, but finally it's working! Thanks :)